# Signal running thread1 to complete method1 after thread2 enters method2

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have 2 methods which need to function as below.

```
method1 {
  1. run logic and insert into table1
}

method2 {
  1. wait till other threads finish method1
  2. block future threads from starting method1
  3. update table1
}
```

The easiest solution would be to synchronize both method1 and method2. Another point of consideration is that method1 can be invoked by multiple threads (>10) and is common operation, while method2 is called very very rarely. So, synchronizing method1 will seriously hamper multiprocessing capability.

I explored the possibility of using ReadWriteLock, with a readLock in method1 and writeLock in method2. But that doesn't help me with #1 in method2, ie. after a  writeLock is acquired in method2, I want running threads in method1 to complete before I proceed method2.

Comment: I thought attempting to take a write lock waits for all read locks to unlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic usage of `ReadWriteLock`.

See [Java Concurrency with ReadWriteLock](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/java-concurrency-with-readwritelock.html)

> The read lock may be held simultaneously by multiple reader threads,
>   so long as there are no writers. **The write lock is exclusive**.

So when you request a write lock in #1 of `method2` it will wait until a time when all read locks have been released by anyone calling `method1` before taking the lock and returning.

Taking a write lock essentially performs both #1 and #2 of `method2`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I am having issues because of the underlying hibernate session being shared in multiple threads.